# How much & How long I can draft videos on Youtube

Tags: video, youtube

I want to make a video channel on youtube. But I don't want to publish any video before 1st January. But I will upload everyday. So, I need to draft all those video till it's 1st January.

So, My Questions-
1. How much video I can draft on youtube at a time?
2. For how long I can draft video on youtube?

Optional Question -
1. If I schedule those video, is it hamper on SEO (Indexing on google?) 
2. If I make those privet and next I make them Public is it good for SEO?

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the videos as private or unlisted then change them to public when you want them to appear.

I don't think it hurts SEO since the video's upload date is reset to the day you publicize it. I've been using the scheduler on my channel and it seems to be doing just fine with SEO.